# Floating Point arithmetic help in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am attempting to finish this piece of an assembly program that multiplies a user provided decimal number by the appropriate power of 10 based on a user provided precision value. However, I keep getting a result that is either in scientific notation or is NaN. I am about 80% sure the problem lies within how the values are being loaded into the FPU stack, but no amount of troubleshooting within my realm of knowledge has been fruitful. What am I missing here?

The example userInput value I am using is 1.23456
The example precisionValue I am using is 2
This should multiply to result in 123.456

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.DATA
    inputPrompt         BYTE "Enter a number with at least 5 decimal places: ", 0
    precisionPrompt     BYTE "Enter a precision value (1, 2, 3, or 4): ", 0
    multiplyValueMsg    BYTE "Multiply Value: ", 0
    userInput           REAL4 0.0               ; Define a buffer to store the user input as a floating-point value
    precisionValue      DWORD 0                 ; Declare a variable to store the precision value
    multiplyValue       DWORD 0                 ; If precision value = 1, multiply value = 10
                                                ; If precision value = 2, multiply value = 100    
                                                ; If precision value = 3, multiply value = 1000
                                                ; If precision value = 4, multiply value = 10000
    resultMsg           BYTE "   Result: ", 0
    resultValue         REAL4 0.0               ; Define a buffer to store the result as a floating-point value

.CODE

MAIN PROC
    mov edx, OFFSET inputPrompt                 ; Load the address of the input prompt message into the EDX register.
    call WriteString                            ; Call the WriteString function to display the input prompt message.

    mov edx, OFFSET userInput                   ; Load the address of the userInput buffer into the EDX register.
    mov ecx, 101                                ; Set ECX to 101, specifying the maximum number of characters to read.
    call ReadString                             ; Call the ReadString function to read user input into the userInput buffer.

    ; Prompt the user to enter a precision value.
    mov edx, OFFSET precisionPrompt             ; Load the address of the precision prompt message into EDX.
    call WriteString                            ; Call WriteString to display the precision prompt message.
    call ReadInt                                ; Call ReadInt to read the user's precision input (as an integer) into EAX.
    mov precisionValue, eax                     ; Store the user's precision input in the 'precisionValue' variable.

    ; Calculate multiplyValue based on precisionValue
    mov eax, precisionValue                     ; Load the precisionValue into EAX for comparison
    cmp eax, 1                                  ; Compare precisionValue with 1
    je precision1                               ; If it's equal to 1, jump to precision1
    cmp eax, 2                                  ; Compare precisionValue with 2
    je precision2                               ; If it's equal to 2, jump to precision2
    cmp eax, 3                                  ; Compare precisionValue with 3
    je precision3                               ; If it's equal to 3, jump to precision3
    cmp eax, 4                                  ; Compare precisionValue with 4
    je precision4                               ; If it's equal to 4, jump to precision4
    jmp next                                    ; If none of the above conditions are met, jump to the 'next' label

precision1:
    mov multiplyValue, 10                       ; If precisionValue is 1, set multiplyValue to 10
    jmp next                                    ; Jump to the 'next' label

precision2:
    mov multiplyValue, 100                      ; If precisionValue is 2, set multiplyValue to 100
    jmp next                 

precision3:
    mov multiplyValue, 1000                     ; If precisionValue is 3, set multiplyValue to 1000
    jmp next                 

precision4:
    mov multiplyValue, 10000                    ; If precisionValue is 4, set multiplyValue to 10000
    jmp next                     

next:
    ; Display the multiplyValue
    mov eax, multiplyValue                      ; Load multiplyValue into EAX for display
    mov edx, OFFSET multiplyValueMsg            ; Load the address of the message into EDX
    call WriteString                            ; Display the message
    call WriteDec                               ; Display the value of multiplyValue as an integer

    ; Calculate the result by multiplying userInput by multiplyValue
    fld userInput                               ; Load the user input onto the FPU stack
    fild dword ptr [multiplyValue]              ; Load multiplyValue as an integer onto the FPU stack
    fmul                                        ; Multiply the two values
    fstp dword ptr resultValue                  ; Store the result in the 'resultValue' variable as a floating-point value

    ; Display the calculated result with the desired precision
    mov edx, OFFSET resultMsg
    call WriteString                            ; Display the result message
    fld resultValue                             ; Load the result value from memory onto the FPU stack
    call WriteFloat                             ; Display the value of the result as a floating-point number


MAIN ENDP

END MAIN
```

I have attemped to work with other variable types and changing the order of loading values onto the stack with the expectation that the incorrect result is just due to the mildly sloppy code, but no luck. I admittedly have little experience with x86 assembly language, esspecially floating point arithmetic within assembly.

Comment: "result that is either in scientific notation" - why would this be a problem?

Comment: What exactly do you get for your sample input?

Comment: Is the result "in scientific notation" *correct*?  Or do you mean it's something tiny like `1.23e-38`?  It does appear from the comments in https://gist.github.com/soachishti/a4d7bb15ee6519f61c0a that `WriteFloat` is supposed to take its input arg in `st0`, the top of the x87 register stack.  (Unlike standard calling conventions which don't pass FP args in registers.)  Your code using `fmul` doesn't balance the x87 stack: it does two pushes but only one `fstp` pop.  Use `fimul dword ptr [multiplyValue]` or something, or `fmulp` if you want to be able to look at both inputs in a debugger.

Comment: The result is not correct. The program is loading example userInput valie 1.23456 onto the stack, but when debugging, the stack shows value +1.2353514249945978e-0307  and when it pushes the multiplyValue of 100, the stack shows +1.0000000000000000e+0002. This is where my confusing is.

Comment: `1e+2` is `100`. The other is not correct, maybe you need to force `dword ptr` everywhere, e.g. `fld dword ptr userInput`

Comment: What writes a 32-bit `float` to `userInput`?  Probably nothing.  Earlier in your program, you do `mov edx, OFFSET userInput` / ... / `call ReadString`, so there are ASCII bytes there, not a float.  (And you pass a size of 101, allowing user input to overwrite all the later stuff in your .data section if the user types a lot before pressing return.  Use a separate buffer with more space for text input.) Is there no ReadFloat function?  Writing an accurate and correct `atof` is hard, especially if you want it to work over the full range of float (so the integer part might not fit in int64_t)